# Is there a jQuery selector that differentiates between elements with text and elements without?

Tags: jquery

I'm not looking for specific text or substrings. I just want those elements whose `textContent` is some non-zero-length string. Does jQuery offer a selector expression that is more time efficient than looping through `$("*")` checking for presence or absence of text?

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/empty-selector/ ?

Comment: `*:not(:empty)'`but under the hood it would be basically doing the check.

Comment: `:empty` means empty of text? I thought it meant empty of descendants. Thanx.

Comment: Ah, "including text nodes".

Comment: So I take it `:parent` is equivalent to `:not(:empty)`?

Comment: @Lori looks like it from the way they are both defined but use the not empty version since it is css and will be faster in js